# Help with SOQL Lookup Relationship

Tags: soql, community

Why is this statement wrong? I got an error when executing this statement in developer console.

```
SELECT Id, Account_Name__r.Name, Account__r.Account_No__c  From CBR__c
```

CBR_ is a child object to Account and Account_Name__c is a lookup field to Account.

```
SELECT Id, Account_Name__r.Name, Account__r.Account_No__c  From CBR__c
                             ^
```

ERROR at Row:1:Column:34

> Didn't understand relationship 'Account__r' in field path. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r'
>   after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: What do you mean by wrong? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, I got an error.

Comment: It will definitely help if you can you update the question with the error that you got

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a little bit correction in your query

```
SELECT Id, Account_Name__r.Name, Account_Name__r.Account_No__c  From CBR__c
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

The error is in `Account__r`,Since your lookup name is `Account_Name__r`.

Try below if `Account_No__c` is a custom field in Account object.

```
SELECT Id, Account_Name__r.Name, Account_Name__r.Account_No__c  From CBR__c
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the correct api name of your lookup field in your query. thats why you are getting an error

Try using this :

```
SELECT Id, Account_Name__r.Name, Account_Name__r.Account_No__c  From CBR__c
```